# Image Upload Functionlity in wit.ai, without using facebook messenger

Tags: python, nlp, chat, chatbot, wit.ai

I am developing a chat-bot using [`wit.ai`](http://wit.ai) and my own UI instead of facebook messenger. I am using `python` to implement actions. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40700506/message-sent-but-not-returning-intend-wit-ai) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40521633/how-to-answer-back-with-images-in-wit-ai) gives some insights about how this can be done in facebook messenger. However I want to have image upload and display functionality in my own UI, which uses `wit.ai`. How can this be done?

My current code can extract an `intent` named `upload` and call `uploadImage()` function. What should be there in `uploadImage()` function that can upload an image and even display in Chat UI?

Answer (score 1):

The following works for a general Python program.  I am not sure it is the proper way to do it with wit.ai.

If you want to do image processing on the image I recommend the [OpenCV library](http://opencv.org/).  Using that and the [easygui](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/easygui) library you can prompt the user for an image, read it, and display it.  The following code shows how do to it.  The dialog box defaults to the folder "c:\" and has filters for png and jpg files.  You will need to figure out how to display the image in your UI.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import easygui

# Prompt the user to open a file.
file_path = easygui.fileopenbox(msg='Locate an image file',
                            filetypes=["*.png", "*.jpg"],
                            title='Specify the image file to upload', 
                            default='c:\*.png')
# Load an image
img = cv2.imread(file_path)
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Yes, but while this could perfectly work, I need a solution to integrate it with wit.ai.